# Problems with range selector on highcharts (highstock)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using two different charts of highstock, both of them have 2 series. Both charts are loaded in the same div depends which button is selected. To do this I set the series data when the user push the other buttons, the problem that I'm having is that in one chart I can select a minimum range of about 10 minutes, but in the other chart I can't select a range lower than one hour. Both are made with the same settings, the only different is that one have numbers with decimals and the other don't.

I want that you can select a range, change graph and keep in the other the selection. This work when the selection is bigger than 1 hour.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use setExtremes() function which allows to define range.
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.setExtremes

Comment: My problems is not the extremes of the chart, is the range selection that i do manually with the navigator.

Comment: @GabrielCandia So you would like to control which "button" is clicked, after loading appropriate type of chart?

Comment: Not exactly, the thing is that in one of the two charts i can´t select with the navigator (manually not with button like 1M for example) a lower range to show than 1 hour, and in the other i can do it without problem. Both have the same configuration.

Comment: Have you tried to set minRange parameter ? http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.minRange

Comment: Thanks, minRange do the job :).